# fabric practically not working after installation on Mac OS 10.13.5

Tags: python, fabric

I have a very basic problem with the fabric library, after I installed it on my mac via pip.

```
$ pip install fabric
```

(I already tried it with sudo. Makes no difference)

Installation worked fine I think.

```
$ fab -V 
Fabric 2.2.2
Paramiko 2.4.1
Invoke 1.1.1
```

But if I follow the fabric tutorial (http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.14/tutorial.html), and try the very first step -creating the fabfile.py with the hello task- It always fails with:

```
$ fab hello
No idea what 'hello' is!
```

I am in the right directory and the file exits. I followed exactly the steps given in the tutorial.

Does anybody have a clue what the problem might be? I wasn't able to find a solution anywhere online.

Comment: For all who may face the same issue, I got an solution a few weeks ago, but I forgot to post it here, sorry for that. I contacted the fabric support. They recommended to install the old fabric version instead of fabric 2. For my purposes all the fabric 1 features are suitable enough. To get the older version just run:  pip install "fabric<2"

Comment: I'm on macOS 10.12.6 (Sierra) and still having same problem.
I'm using python 3.6.2 if it matters. (I upgraded fabric version to get python3 support)

Comment: @MandarVaze I took a look at your code you posted below. I don't know if you have tried it yet, but name your file with the tasks not 'tasks.py' but 'fabfile.py' so you won't need a additional path or command to tell fabric where the tasks are. Also I used the following imports in my fabfile. Give it a try, I hope it works. `from fabric.api import run, settings, cd, shell_env, env, parallel, hosts, reboot, execute`
`from fabric.contrib.console import confirm`

Comment: See solution on github : https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/1854#issuecomment-429868443
TL;DR: `fab -c tasks build` worked (in my case)

Comment: run fab --list to see if it outputs your task

Answer (score 4):

You are reading the documentation of Fabric 1.14, while you are using v2.2

In Fabric 2+, you have to wrap your `hello` function with a `@task` decorator (and of course import the `task` module)

Please refer to the first part of the [docs](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.2/getting-started.html), *Addendum: the fab command-line tool* section for more details :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for my very late response. I have already tried to that before I asked my question here on stackoverflow but that also did not help. And I have also seen that the documentation is not up to date, but it was the only one I found.

Comment: I've posted my "test" file (which has `@task` as well as `from fabric import task` statement) here : https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/1854#issuecomment-429545180
It is still not working.